# Error equation for distance between points in spherical coordinates

Tags: error-propagation

(Question brought over from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1600069/error-in-distance-between-points-in-spherical-coordinates), after asking [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3012/can-i-post-a-statistics-related-question-here-that-got-no-answer-in-mathematics))

Consider two points with spherical coordinates: $a=(r_1,\theta_1,\phi_1)$ and $b=(r_2,\theta_2,\phi_2)$. The cartesian coordinates of the points are:

$$ (r_i \cos\theta_i \cos\phi_i, r_i \cos\theta_i \sin\phi_i, r_i\sin\theta_i);\;\;i=[1, 2]$$

so the distance between the two points is given by:

$$ d= \sqrt{r_1^2+r_2^2-2r_1r_2\left(\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_2\cos(\phi_1-\phi_2)+\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2\right)}$$

as stated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1078262/37846).

I need to calculate the error associated with $d$, assuming that only the distances and not the angles have uncertainties assigned, that is: $r_i\pm \sigma_i$. I re-write $d$ as:

$$ d= \sqrt{r_1^2+r_2^2-2r_1r_2A}$$

and use the [standard formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty#Simplification) for obtaining $\sigma_d$:

$$\sigma_d = \sqrt{ \left(\frac{\partial d}{\partial {r_1} }\right)^2 \sigma_1^2 + \left(\frac{\partial d}{\partial {r_2} }\right)^2 \sigma_2^2}$$

assuming no covariances between $r_1, r_2$. I obtain the following relation:

$$\sigma_d = \frac{1}{d}\sqrt{ \left(r_1-r_2*A\right)^2 \sigma_1^2 + \left(r_2-r_1*A\right)^2 \sigma_2^2}$$

Is this final equation correct? I am particularly concerned about the $1/d$ term which lowers the error for larger values of $d$.

Comment: A quick and easy way to check is to perform a units analysis: because $d$ is distance and so are the $r_i$, $\sigma_d$ had better be a distance, too.

Comment: Thanks whuber. As far as I can tell, the units are preserved. I didn't notice I lost factors of 2, I'll check that out now. Other than that, is the error analysis correct? Mainly the use of the uncertainty propagation formula is what concerns me.

Comment: Just doing the math blindly, I got (@d/@r1)^2 as 1. Are you sure you took your derivatives correctly?

Comment: You mean $(\delta d/\delta r_1)^2$? I get $[(r_1-A r_2)/d]^2$, please see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diff+sqrt(r1%5E2%2Br2%5E2-2*r1*r2*A)).